# There was an error getting a Chat authorization token. Refresh and try again

Tags: chatbot, azure-bot-service

I recently created a chatbot via http://dev.botframework.com/bots (the page initially displayed the info that I did not have any bots). The form redirected me to Azure Portal where I chose a new "Web App Bot" option. I also created all required resources (RG and even setup a new tenant with admin rights).
After successful deployment I got the following issues:

- *Test in Web Chat* in bot settings (Azure Portal) shows "There was an error getting a Chat authorization token. Refresh and try again."
- *Channels* in bot settings shows "Unable to find the bot with the specified id."
- dev.botframework.com/bots shows there are no bots created

Have anyone had this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I also get same issue and it got resolved, Please refer below url , it may help you as well.

https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/issues/1068